# set array adapter list view

Tags: android, arraylist, android-listview, dataadapter

This code works in BlueStacks, but when the smart phone running the following error in the log display.

Error:

```
The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a 
notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a
background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls
notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(2131296334, class
android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter)]
```

Code:

```
private void displayResultList() {

        try {
        array.clear();
        array=baseHelper.results;
        tView.setText("Size : " +array.size()+" "+ baseHelper.countmcur );

            try {

                if(arrayAdapter!=null)
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 arrayAdapter=new display();
                listV.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (Exception e) {
             message.messages(contex, e.getMessage());
            }

            listV.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
             message.messages(contex, e.getMessage());
        }


        }
```

Comment: From where are you calling displayResultList? In case this is an asynctask, from doInBackground or from onPostExecute?

Comment: @Mdlc,button.setOnClickListener

Answer (score 0):

after you change your Data from your adapter, you should call notifyDataChange.
next, debug your code to find out which column rise error.
Apart from this, try this code inside "TRY CATCH" dear friend if there is a risk to rise an error